# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'

Tags: selenium-webdriver, anaconda, python-3.7

I have upgraded to Selenium 4.1.3, and it's caused a problem.

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\TestPlan>python TestPlan_Something.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TestPlan_Something.py", line 8, in <module>
    from TestCases.Test import Test
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\TestPlan\TestCase\Test.py", line 56, in <module>
    from Util.WebDriverEventListener import WebDriverEventListener as Listener
  File "..\Util\WebDriverEventListener.py", line 30, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.support.events import AbstractEventListener
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\Python\lib\selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\Python\lib\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 27, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\Python\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 39, in <module>
    from .remote_connection import RemoteConnection
  File "C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\Python\lib\selenium\webdriver\remote\remote_connection.py", line 26, in <module>
    import certifi
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'certifi'
```

As far as I can tell certifi is installed in the following directory: C:\Users\me\Desktop\TA\Python\Lib\site-packages\pip_vendor.

I'm not sure what the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

In the file *remote_connection.py* I replaced `sys.path.append()` with `sys.path.insert(0, path)` and passed in the filepath string "...\Python\Lib\site_packages\pip\_vendor" as path.